# Subversion - 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: svn

I tried to setup a Subversion server and now I have a problem: I have a 403 Forbidden error on the http://blabla.com/svn page and also the http://blabla.com/svn/MyRepo.

I looked at the Apache error log and I have the error: "The URI does not contain the name of a repository. [403, #190001]"

Here is my dav_svn configuration:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /var/svn
  SVNListParentPath On

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  Require valid-user

</Location>
```

**EDIT: I've found the solution, my authz file was just wrong!**

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is more of a programming-related question than it is a server admin question... Maybe the admin-experts over at SuperUser can help you debug this :)

Comment: Are your repositories directly under `/var/svn`?

Comment: @steffen Yes they are

Comment: Did you try with trailing slash on `/var/svn`? And did you check the permisssions? May Apache read /var/svn?

Comment: @steffen Even with the trailing slash it doesn't work, and yes Apache can read /var/svn

Comment: Could you solve issue? @MinusKube

Comment: @ÖmrümÇetin Yes, I think the problem was simply the authz file being invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, the problem was the .authz file being invalid (wrong syntax).